# Create a new column based on a condition in existing column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column humidity_category based on the values in the relative humidity column. Specifically, I want to categorize the humidity levels as follows:

1. If relative humidity is greater than 90, it should be categorized as >90%.
2. If relative humidity` is greater than BOTH 80 and 90, it should be categorized as >80%.

Comment: It's not clear what the end result should look like from the question - one of your criteria is a subset of the other. For example, what category should a value of e.g. 96 take? What category should a value of 87 take?

Comment: Still unclear. So what sort of data result are you expecting?

Comment: Your "glimpse" of data contradicts your comment. For instance, `97.2` should be both `>90%` and `>80 & <=100`, but instead it is only `>90%`. You either need multiple categorical columns (does not seem right for this), or you need mutually-exclusive levels of your categories, such as `>90%` and `>80 & <=90%`, etc.

Comment: Change that ... if you want to know the "presence" (set membership) in zero or more groups, then you need either a list-column or multiple vector columns.

Comment: Your plot of data suggests at least one other numeric column, so I suggest either removing the [tag:ggplot2] tag or make this question more reproducible by sharing the plot code and a sample of the data that you're using. BTW, even if you have two categs for one data point, plotting both categories is a bit challenging to do clearly, needing either alpha, jitter/dodge, or facets to be able to see that one data point has multiple categs assigned.

Comment: That's the point: a _single_ column can contain up to a single category (as far as ggplot is concerned), there is no _direct_ way for a simple vector to clearly indicate set membership in multiple sets.

Comment: You replaced the [tag:ggplot2] tag with [tag:plot] but there is still no code, so ... still no idea what you intend for how to plot a single data point with multiple categories. Do you want it to be two perfectly-overlapping points? Do the two colors (assuming `aes(color=humidity_catog)`) have transparency so that you somehow see it differently?

Comment: How in Excel can you have one data point have two categories identified in one cell? If you're doing string-concatenation, then even in Excel that row is not in two categories, it is in a third category that is just a longer string. I do plots in R and python and Excel, and ... you're suggesting a notion of "two differentiable properties assigned to a single cell", which takes extra effort to be able to use ... and even then, they ways to use it generally duplicate the row so that it has _one_ of each property in each of its otherwise duplicative rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating two data frames and then combined them using bind_rows function

```
>80 <- df %>%
  filter(humidity > 80) %>%
  mutate(humidity_category = ">80%")

>90 <- df %>%
  filter(humidity > 90) %>%
  mutate(humidity_category = ">90%")


combined_df <- bind_rows(>80, >90)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make points belong to multiple groups (so they get plotted more than once), you could do a join to a table with the group assignments.

Here I make a table with categorizations (noting that they overlap), and join to it. This makes multiple appearances of the 90-100 points since they're in both groups. I'm using `geom_jitter` and some transparency to make this clearer -- otherwise we might just see the version of the points that appear last (so they're plotted last).

```
(lookup_tbl <- data.frame(low = c(90, 80),
          high = c(Inf, 100),
          cat = c(">90", "80-100")))

  low high    cat
1  90  Inf    >90
2  80  100 80-100


library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  mutate(day = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(lookup_tbl, join_by(humidity >= low, humidity <= high)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, humidity, color = cat)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I should be getting two curves not four? One curve for over 90 data points and other curve values from 80.01 to 100. I am thinking that creating two data frames: one for over 90 data points and the other for 80.01 to 100 data points and then combining these two dataframes using `bind_rows` would be an easy option?

Comment: This creates two sets of data for the range 90+, I don't know what you mean about four.  `bind_rows` also works but strikes me as a little unwieldy and manual compared to using a lookup table.

Comment: To confirm, your example df has 80 rows, 69 of which have humidity this both >90 and between 80-100. My code expands the data to 159 rows, because it adds 69 rows for those observations that are in both categorizations. Perhaps your original data was distinguished every 20 rows by another column which you did not include in the sample? Absent that I just used the observation # as the x axis.

Comment: Presumably your real data, unlike your example, has data under 80. Should those appear with a third color or not at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255580/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-ahsk).